# Azure Data Flow - dynamically building nested object

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

The use-case seems to be pretty trivial but I can't find any way to achieve it.

Let's say I have multiple input documents like below:

```
[
    { fieldA: 1, fieldB:1 },
    { fieldB: 1, fieldC:1 },
]
```

So the assumption is that the names of the fields are totally dynamic. The data will be coming from multiple csv files.

The goal is to take advantage of CosmosDB and insert those documents into a single collection this way:

```
[
    metadata: "abc", attributes: { fieldA: 1, fieldB:1 },
    metadata: "xyz", attributes: { fieldB: 1, fieldC:1 }        
]
```

I've been trying to find a way to express this part `attributes: { fieldA: 1, fieldB:1 }` using data flow and [Derived Column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-derived-column). Is there any variable which represents whole input as an object? Something like `$$ROOT` in MongoDB's Aggregation Framework would be great. I also tried to use [columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expression-functions#columns) expression but can't find any good example which demonstrates how to process the output of this expression into a nested object.